# Select options are not appearing behind sweet alert popup

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I am using inspinia theme in my project and I have created a form in which I am using sweet alert popup for displaying validation messages on a search button click. Now when the validation messages appear on the screen, the select options are getting displayed over the popup as shown in the screenshot below. [image]

I have tried to use the below css in order to make select options displayed behind the popup but it failed. I tried a lot of other things but could not find anything. Please help !!!

```
    <style>
        select.form-control option {
            z-index: 100 !important;
        }

        div.sweet-overlay {
            z-index: 999999 !important;
            overflow-y: visible !important;
        }

        div.sweet-alert {
            z-index: 999999999;
        }
    </style>
```

HTML

```
    <form class="form-horizontal">
       .........
            <div class="form-group ">
                                        <label class="control-label col-sm-4 required"> Discount Type
                                            <span id="" class="tooltip-Demo"></span> </label>
                                        <div class="col-sm-6">
                                            <select type="text" name="" id="dcType" class="form-control">
                                                <option value="">Select an Option</option>


                                            <option rel="customDc" data-action="" value="cDc">Custom Discount</option></select>

                                        </div>

                                    </div>

             ................
            </form>
```

Comment: i guess it would be best to apply a z-index to your parent which is DIV. and better to show your html as well

Comment: i tried  .form-horizontal {
                z-index: 100 !important;
            }          it also failed

Comment: Ok would you update your question to add your html file.

Comment: sorry it is very big file

Comment: you just need to show your problems only not all your html file. you only need to show your select tag parent element and your popup dialog parent elemet with their css.

Comment: the actual css are present in the theme which are included in common files. I am using the above style tag code for overwriting the existing css. when i inspect the element in the browser, they are getting overwritten but not affecting the HTML elements